# How to escape {0} from Console.Write()

Tags: c#

Consider below output

```
'{0}' is replaced to 'Hello'
```

To print above text I can write this

```
Console.Write("'{0}' is replaced to '{1}'", "{0}", "Hello");
```

But here I want to use single argument to be passed for that string

```
Console.Write("'{0}' is replaced to '{0}'", "Hello");
                 ^to escape somehow this
```

I want to escape first '{0}'. I tried this

```
Console.Write("'\\{0}' is replaced to '{0}'", "Hello");
```

Output

```
'\Hello' is replaced to 'Hello'
```

Is there any way to print '{0}' instead of replacing it with first argument of that string (i.e. second argument of Console.Write(...) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `string.Format` and methods that use string args ie `Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()`  or *String Interpolation*,  you use double braces

I.e

use  `{{ blah }}` to encode literal `{ blah }`.

or

use  `{{0}}` to encode literal `{0}`.

use  `I need braces {{ for some reason` to encode  `I need braces { for some reason`

[`string.Format` Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

> How do I include literal braces ("{" and "}") in the result string?
>   For example, how do you prevent the following method call from
>   throwing a FormatException exception?

```
result = String.Format("The text has {0} '{' characters and {1} '}' characters.", nOpen, nClose);
```

> A single opening or closing brace is always interpreted as the
>   beginning or end of a format item. To be interpreted literally, it
>   must be escaped. You escape a brace by adding another brace ("{{" and
>   "}}" instead of "{" and "}"), as in the following method call:

```
result = String.Format("The text has {0} '{{' characters and {1} '}}' characters.", nOpen, nClose);
```

> However, even escaped braces are easily misinterpreted. We recommend
>   that you include braces in the format list and use format items to
>   insert them in the result string, as the following example shows.

```
result = String.Format("The text has {0} '{1}' characters and {2} '{3}' characters.", nOpen, "{", nClose, "}");
```

Answer (score 1):

using `Console.Write("\'{0}\' is replaced to '{1}'", "{0}", "Hello");`

Output : `'{0}' is replaced to 'Hello'`

using `Console.Write("{{0}} is replaced to '{1}'", "{0}", "Hello");`

Output : `{0} is replaced to 'Hello'`

Answer (score 1):

In `C#6` and above you cans use [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings):

```
string hello = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine($"'{{0}}' is replaced to '{hello}'");
```

Or below `C#6`

```
string hello = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine("'{{0}}' is replaced to '{0}'", hello);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write("'{{0}}' is replaced to '{0}'", "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is that what you want :
 1. `Console.WriteLine($"{{0}} is replaced to '{"Hello"}'");`
 2. `Console.WriteLine("{{0}} is replaced to '{0}'","Hello");`